# May versus would

Tags: word-choice

Which one of the sentences is the correct/preferable one?

> May you send me a screenshot of the application you are developing?

> Would you send me a screenshot of the application you are developing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them are grammatically correct but the first one is semantically wrong. So you can use the second one but I'd prefer:

> Could you send me a screenshot of the
>   application you are developing?

Even politer:

> Would you mind sending me a screenshot of the
>   application you are developing?

Comment: I have always thought that a sentence starting with "may" should be polite. Next time I will trust my fiancee, and follow what she suggested me to write. `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno You are right that "may" is polite; the problem is that "may" is used for permission, so normally you would never ask the other person if they have permission to do something (it is like saying "are you allowed to send me...").

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I see; it's completely different from what I meant.

Comment: The first sentence isn't correct.

Comment: Yet another wrong answer accepted. Even worse is getting someone who starts a sentence with "Your both sentences" telling us what is or isn't grammatically correct.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: Would you mind posting the right answer to let us know the truth?

Comment: If someone asked me "could you send" I might reply "I could!" since _could_ is a near synonym of _can_ which is asking about ability, not inclination or action. "Would you" is better and colloquially common, though "would you mind" seems to ask a conditional without stating the condition such as "if I asked you to, would you mind ..." So how about "do you mind?" All the shenanigans can be eliminated, though, by simply saying "Please send" and adding "if you don't mind" if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I would say

> Would you send me a screenshot of the application you are developing?

or like Mehper said

> Would you mind sending me a screenshot of the application you are developing?

Because "May you..." sounds funny and I think "Could you..." asks if they have the ability to.